# Applying a function to multiple columns of same dataframe

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a difference in performance when if I apply some function

- dynamically in a loop over column names vs
- statically by hardcoding column names

E.g.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import upper

df = spark.read...
cols_to_change = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

for c in cols_to_change:
    df = df.withColumn(f'{c}_upper', upper(c))

df.write...

#    ---- VS ----

df = spark.read...

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('c1_upper', upper('c1'))
    .withColumn('c2_upper', upper('c2'))
    .withColumn('c3_upper', upper('c3'))
)

df.write...
```

My guess was that they would perform the same (discounting the python overhead of course), because until an action (like `write()`/`count()`) is executed, the spark engine will just keep building the plan, but not execute anything.

In my case it's ~50 columns.

Comment: side note -- multiple `withColumn` chains will create a projection for each of them. it is better to create multiple columns within a single `select`, if possible.

Comment: @samkart I feel like this is not true any more in Spark3.  If you see `explain` with chain of `withColumn`, you see all `withColumn` are squashed into a single projection (`CollapseProject`).

Comment: @Emma interesting find. however, in my tests, i don't see `CollapseProject` but it does look like the optimized plan squashes multiple `withColumn` calls into a single projection. +1 (spark 3.4)

Comment: Yeah, "CollapseProject" won't appear as text but it is what they call this optimization.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same in terms of Spark. Spark is lazy evaluation, no matter what kind of transformations are called, the DAG and processes are built only when the action is called. You can check and compare both df by using `explain()` to see the execution plan (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain.html).